# hook_commerce_checkout_complete is never called

Tags: 8, commerce, hooks

I need to send out a PDF via mail upon order completion, and according to [DrupalContrib](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21checkout%21commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_complete/8), I can use `hook_commerce_checkout($order)` to achieve this.

this is my module code:

```
<?php

function pdf_checkout_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {
  // No example.
  \Drupal::logger('pdf_checkout')->info('Hook called.');
}
```

My problem is, that it is never called, I've tried everything from just sending a log message when it is used, to creating a new, clean, module just to test it.
None of it has worked.

Is the hook still being used in Commerce 2.x? If not, what should I look at instead to achieve a similar effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show your exact code in the custom module ?

Comment: @OlegVidenov, added, it's not much, as I've disabled my previous module and now only run this extremely short one, it only serves the purpose to send a log message if the hook is called, which it doesn't.

Comment: that is weird. http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21cart%21commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_commerce_checkout_complete/8 , can you just as test add if any code there is still executed ?

Comment: as a test, can you make some syntax error in your module, just to ensure the code is being read at all

Comment: @OlegVidenov, removed the semicolon, gave me a *ParseError:* syntax error message about it, so the module is being read. I can Zip and link my module, but it is literally only the code mentioned above.

Comment: I wouldn't trust anything found on drupalcontrib. Last I saw most of it was fairly out of date. Only use the official docs on drupal.org and ones provided with the module.

Comment: @Kevin, I would love to use the official api, but the commerce module doesn't seem to have any *.api.php files for me to browse through, and I can't find any other source for a full list of commerce API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the hook still being used in Commerce 2.x?

No.

> If not, what should I look at instead to achieve a similar effect?

Commerce 8.x-2.x depends on the state_machine module which has events that are triggered when an order is placed (=checkout complete) as well as other state changes.

See [Assigning (adding) an entity reference when an Order process is completed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232318/assigning-adding-an-entity-reference-when-an-order-process-is-completed/232323#232323)